# Jmeter and openldap

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use Jmeter to load test an openldap mstaer/slave cluster.
I want to simulate a large number of users searching openldap but connecting to the slave. 
My slave is behind an LB but not the master so I only have access to the slave.

Jmeter tries to update the openldap and since it's a replica it fails. Does anyone know
how to configure Jmeter just to do a search and no updates?

Thanks
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to use only `Search test` in the [LDAP Extended Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#LDAP_Extended_Request) sampler and JMeter won't modify any data there:

[image]

You may also be interested in [How to Load Test LDAP with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ldap-apache-jmeter) which covers all the aspects of the OpenLDAP (and compatible directory servers) load testing using JMeter

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am still not having any luck with the search. this is what I get. Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2020-05-03 20:50:06 EDT
Load time:1
Connect Time:0
Latency:0
Size in bytes:375
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes:0
Body size in bytes:375
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:800
Response message:javax.naming.NamingException: Context is null
what is this Search base: cn=TestGroup,cn=Groups, dn=test, dn=com. do I have to have cn=TestGroup,cn=Groups? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you first need to open the "context", i.e.:

- Add LDAP Extended Request with `Thread Bind`
- Then you can add another LDAP Extended request (e.g. Search)
- Finally last LDAP Extended Request to do Thread Unbind.